# HTML Character � is Displayed instead of è in translations between English and French

Tags: html, encoding, meta

I have the following sentence:

```
fr['client_id_label'] = " paramètres"  ; 
en['client_id_label']= "Client ID";
$("div[id='client_id_label']").text(langResources[$("div[id='client_id_label']").prop("id")]);
```

Why is '�' displayed instead of 'è' when this is executed?

Comment: 2 things to check : charset-UTF8 is there? are you cpying this info from some text/doc file? if yes use your keyboard for single and double quotes(' and ")

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the meta charset for your website. example:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Search: html5 meta charset

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't work. Is there any other settings that need to change also, Thanks

Comment: figure out what charset you want to use, and use it for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file is using UTF-8 encoding, or use HTML char codes for special characters; that fancy è up there is `&#232;`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this you could use a **unicode table** to show special characters in jquery text; in this case:

```
fr['client_id_label'] = " param\u00E8tres";
```

Because `\u00E8`  = è

[image: unicode table]

Comment: This is kind of bad advice, because it's a workaround to the core issue. The characters should just work. Either the source file is not really UTF-8, or the browser is not interpreting the characters as such. My guess is the first.